# Can Web Deploy also take care of dependencies?

Tags: iis, deployment, installation, webdeploy

I'm looking for a way to deploy an ASP.NET MVC website including all of it's dependencies such as .NET framework or ASP.NET MVC 3.

I found out how to dump a list of all of my dependencies with web deploy, but can it also actually deploy all of these dependencies?

If not, what other (hopefully not too expensive) options do I have? Installaware seems to be able to do this, but it's a bit too pricey for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Deploy (MSDeploy) can list the dependencies as you mentioned however it does not provide a automated way of packaging and deploying those larger type dependencies (like Frameworks or Features).

Using the [Web Deploy runCommand Provider](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it can be used to deploy .Net frameworks,  ASP.NET MVC 3. but you will need to write your own deployment manifests and deployment batch files.

Alternatively you can use powershell or psexec for your deployments

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. For those also interested in this topic, you'll need this documentation for scripting WebPi: http://blogs.iis.net/satishl/archive/2011/01/26/webpi-command-line.aspx